# How to input \t from asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to input a control character from an asp.net form.  For example I want a user to be able to enter \t into a text box and it be \t not \ \t (The space is there as one of them gets escaped if I put them together). What's the best way to go with this? I've been staring at it continuously now for quite a while and the answer isn't jumping out at me.  Thanks.

Update:

Thanks guys, but I've just answered myself.

I've just found in Regex the static Unescape method, so in my web app I am now doing:

(Where tb is an asp.net TextBox)

```
        var inputText = tb.Text;
        if (inputText.Length == 2)
        {
            var escaped = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(inputText);
            if (escaped.Length == 1)
            {
                var character = escaped.ToCharArray()[0];
                if (char.IsControl(character))
                {
                    inputText = character.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I can't answer myself yet on SO but I've found the answer. Its the Regex the static Unescape method.  var escaped = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(inputText);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, but I've just answered myself.

I've just found in Regex the static Unescape method, so in my web app I am now doing:

(Where tb is an asp.net T

```
        var inputText = tb.Text;
        if (inputText.Length == 2)
        {
            var escaped = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(inputText);
            if (escaped.Length == 1)
            {
                var character = escaped.ToCharArray()[0];
                if (char.IsControl(character))
                {
                    inputText = character.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to parse an escaped char like `'\t'`. If so use this helper method:

```
public static char ParseChar(string ch)
{
    char result;

    if (ch[0] != '\\')
        result = ch[0];
    else
    {
        if (ch.Length == 1)
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid escape sequence '" + ch + "'");

        switch (ch[1])
        {
            case '\'': result = '\''; break;
            case '"': result = '"'; break;
            case '\\': result = '\\'; break;
            case '0': result = '\0'; break;
            case 'a': result = '\a'; break;
            case 'b': result = '\b'; break;
            case 'f': result = '\f'; break;
            case 'n': result = '\n'; break;
            case 't': result = '\t'; break;
            case 'v': result = '\v'; break;

            default:
                throw new ArgumentException(
                    "Invalid escape sequence '" + ch + "'");
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is that if you are looking at a true `\t` through the debugger to visually see the value, .net will automatically encode it with a `\\` for you, even though it's not there.

That said, if it truly is there, you could try to do a search and replace for it after the user submits the text to the server:

```
var newString = stringWithDoubleSlash.Replace("\\\\", "\\");  
// We aren't really looking for 4 slashes, but it appears that way since two of them are escaped
```